# Onclick and submit for toggle button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<button type="submit" id="start-break" name="start" type="button" class="actv-btn-dft1 blbg" onClick="showhide('start-break', 'stop-break');return false;"  title="Start Break">Start Break</button> 
<button type="submit" id="stop-break" type="button" class="actv-btn-dft1 orbg" onClick="showhide('stop-break', 'start-break');return false;"  style="display:none"  title="Stop Break">Stop Break</button>
```

I am using something like a toggle button where click of start makes visible stop then on click of stop start button is visible.

I am using `showhide('start-break', 'stop-break')` JavaScript function as described below:

```
function showhide(hideid,showid)
{
 document.getElementById(showid).style.display='block';
 document.getElementById(hideid).style.display='none';
}
```

I want to know  why I am not able to get the value of the start or stop in the controller.

-> If I remove that return false in the `onclick` I get it submitted but the UI gets disturbed (the button does not remain in the stop position when start is clicked).

Comment: code looks fine. Are you getting any javascript errors on the console?

Comment: What do you mean with "value of the start or stop in the controller"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false;` is blocking the submit. When the form is submitted, the page will of course be refreshed with the response of the form submit request.

Just don't use JS to show/hide the buttons. Use the server side language for this (based on your profile and the edit history you're using "J2EE" and thus you're familiar with JSP):

```html
<c:if test="${empty param.start}">
   <button type="submit" name="start">Start</button>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty param.start}">
   <button type="submit" name="stop">Stop</button>
</c:if>
```

An alternative is to use Ajax to submit the form. But that's a completely different story.

Comment: Thanks balusC!
Your Idea was great ..thanks for understanding the problem . I used <c:choose> and <c:when>  instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `return false;` at the end of the `showHide()` function as opposed to in the elements' `onclick` attribute? If I'm not mistaken, you're not supposed to have multiple javascript statements in one inline attribute.

Comment: you can actually have multiple statements inline

Comment: Better yet: pull the JS out of your HTML elements and attach event listeners between `<script>` tags. Here, I've even done it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aqvdQ/

Answer (score 1):

If nothing happens, could it be that your function declaration is out of window scope? Your code works fine for me in http://jsfiddle.net/TZMkH/1/